# Visual Studio XML comments (summary) and special characters

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a method in a C# / Wpf project and I'd like to comment / document it using the XML comments like this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises Drag & Drop
    /// </summary>
    void initDragDrop()
    {

    }
```

When I now use this method somewhere in my project and hover the mouse over it, I get the message
"XML comment contains invalid XML: At this place, no spaces are allowed" (I translated the text after the colon manually to english, so it may not be literally in your visual studio).
I found out the problem is the "&" sign, if I remove it, it works fine. But I want to keep it, so how to I escape it in the XML summary? I tried "\&" but this isn't working.

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remember that the & character has special meaning in xml (the start of an entity).  You need to write your comment like this instead (annoying, I know):

```
/// <summary>
/// Initialises Drag &amp; Drop
/// </summary>
void initDragDrop()
{

}
```

I might be wrong on this next point, but I don't think you can even use a CDATA section to avoid the entity, because it breaks the comments.  You *must* type out the entire `&amp;` entity.

Comment: Actually, you can use CDATA. Here's an example from one of my projects: http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/network/Show?projectName=kbcsv&changeSetId=42031#530479. Another option is to move the documentation to a separate file altogether and <include/> it into the source file.

Comment: thank you both for your replies! kent, using your link I've seen that your class is well documented. I guess you are generating some kidn of HTML from this? Which tool are you using for this task? Last time I looked for such tools they were all for earlier dot net versions or hard to use for beginners.
I'll accept joels answer, first it's a short solution, second kent added his solution as comment which isn't markable, else I would mark it too ;-)

Comment: oh another question, any chance visual studio shows me directly that i made mistakes in the XML? currently I see the error only when hovering the documented method. A direct error like errors in code would be useful.

Comment: Don't forget you need to do the same for <, > and " (&lt; &gt; &quot;). If you want to generate MSDN-like documentation in HTML, CHM or other formats, you can use free Sandcastle or our VSdocman. VSdocman contains also comment editor which automatically escapes all necessary characters.

Comment: @stefan: I use Sandcastle. You can see the output by downloading the doc from http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/releases/view/36254. You can see how I build the doc in my MSBuild file at http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/network/Show?projectName=kbcsv&changeSetId=42031#530480.